# constexpr template meta-info variable in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, header-only

I'm trying to represent some meta information in a structured way (i.e. using a class). It's header-only and I need to support c++11 so can't use inline variables. I've come up with a couple of potential solutions but each has its drawbacks. Any suggestions would be much appreciated though just pointing on how to make "alternative B" to compile would be a great solution for me.

`SthInfo::fieldA` is used as an argument to a templated `Processor<Type>::work(field)` which :

- checks that the "container type" matches this processor
- and uses the ID together with other non-relevant args do some internal logic

### Alternative A - working but templated ID

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container, int ID>
class FieldInfo {
public:
    static constexpr int id = ID;
};

template <typename T>
class Processor {
public:
    template <typename Container, int ID>
    void work(FieldInfo<Container, ID> field) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<Container, T>::value, "Given field can't be processed - container type mismatch");
        // some business logic using the ID, i.e. accessing `field.id`
        int id = field.id;
    }
};

struct Sth {/* contains fieldA and fieldB - just as an example */};

// SthInfo holds meta-information about fields in Sth
struct SthInfo {
    static constexpr FieldInfo<Sth, 1> fieldA{};
};

int main() {
    Processor<Sth> processor;
    processor.work(SthInfo::fieldA);
}
```

This works (compiles and links) fine on Linux and Windows. However, Is there a way to avoid the `ID` constant in the template and have it as a field in the `FieldInfo` class? Any other improvement ideas?

### Alternative B - broken - won't link

I've tried changing to the following code but it doesn't link on Linux (but does on Windows...) with `undefined reference to SthInfo::fieldA`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container>
class FieldInfo {
public:
    const int id;
};

template <typename T>
class Processor {
public:
    template <typename Container>
    void work(FieldInfo<Container> field) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<Container, T>::value, "Given field can't be processed - container type mismatch");
        // some business logic using the ID, i.e. accessing `field.id`
        int id = field.id;
    }
};

struct Sth {/* contains fieldA and fieldB - just as an example */};

// SthInfo holds meta-information about fields in Sth
struct SthInfo {
    static constexpr FieldInfo<Sth> fieldA{1};
};

int main() {
    Processor<Sth> processor;
    processor.work(SthInfo::fieldA);
}
```

## Alternative C - constexpr function - not so nice to use.

Changing `SthInfo::fieldA` to a constexpr function helps but then you have to use `()` when using in the app code...

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container>
class FieldInfo {
public:
    const int id;
};

template <typename T>
class Processor {
public:
    template <typename Container>
    void work(FieldInfo<Container> field) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<Container, T>::value, "Given field can't be processed - container type mismatch");
        // some business logic using the ID, i.e. accessing `field.id`
        int id = field.id;
    }
};

struct Sth {/* contains fieldA and fieldB - just as an example */};

// SthInfo holds meta-information about fields in Sth
struct SthInfo {
    static constexpr FieldInfo<Sth> fieldA() { return FieldInfo<Sth>{1}; }
};

int main() {
    Processor<Sth> processor;
    processor.work(SthInfo::fieldA());
}
```

Comment: so you just need to change your mind on what is "nice" then you have a nice working solution, no? What is the question?

Comment: @idclev463035818 obviously that's true :), but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution - that's why I'm reaching out to the community

Comment: then you need to explain what you call "more elegant". I am just trying to tease a more specific question out of you ;)

Comment: also it would be good to include [mcve]s. When I see `...` I always get confused (because its either something about variadic templates or incomplete code). If what you have in place of `...` isnt necessary to understand the quesiton you can remove it. If it is necessary you should include it

Comment: I cannot reproduce "but it doesn't link on Linux" for B case. Please, can you include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've changed the description - each tried "solution" is a self-contained main.cpp file

Comment: yeah and clarified the goal - getting alternative B to compile & link.

Comment: BTW I've found out AlternativeB links without issues when specifying c++17 but it doesn't for c++11. Trying to figure out what's wrong because I have to target c++11  :/

Comment: [OT]: Why making template method when only `T` is accepted?

Comment: Processor is a templated class @Jarod42, it has some universal logic but needs to make sure the right processor is used with the right type. The names used are rather auxiliary - I've tried to filter out any details not necessary for the question.

Comment: I meant `template <typename T>
void Processor<T>::work(FieldInfo<T> field)` seems enough, instead of `template <typename T> template<typename T2>
void Processor<T>::work(FieldInfo<T2> field) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, T2>); }`.

Comment: Good point, that should be enough and replaces the static_assert(). Would have to check this whether the given compiler error (in case you used an incompatible field as an argument) would be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to C++17, which introduced inline variables—and made constexpr static member variables implicitly inline—you have to **define** such variables outside the class if they are odr-used:

```
const FieldInfo<Sth> SthInfo::fieldA;
```

Note that this is a non-templated variable and thus must be defined in exactly **one** source file.  Similar definitions of **templated** variables can appear in headers (using the same compiler/linker support as used for inline variables), so you’ll want to use something like

```
template<class T>
struct Info {
    static constexpr FieldInfo<T> fieldA{1};
};
template<class T> const FieldInfo<T> Info<T>::fieldA;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't work for me since those classes are part of the (generated) header-only code. I've already tried that and can't make it work for c++11 even by using `inline` because that's c++17 only :/

Comment: @vaind: I didn’t see any restriction in the question on changing the `SthInfo` class—indeed, you showed three different versions of it.  Did I misunderstand, or did I just inadequately emphasize the approach that can be header-only?